# Where did my extra reputation come from?

Tags: support

I suddenly got 2 points of extra reputation:

[image: rep1]

But looking at the itemized display, it doesn't appear (image from the same time.)

[image: rep2]

Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Stefan's comment "Perhaps somebody removed a downvote, which would add +2" is the best answer you can get. I tried to verify Stefan's explanation, but that might be impossible:

My first thought was that it should be possible to see from the timeline of the posts you contributed to if there was a downvote retracted. Now I had a look at [the timeline of one of my questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/3259/timeline). I gave a self-answer that got 1 upvote and 1 downvote on 22 September (the latter one can see from my comment), but the timeline shows 2 *upvotes* on that day! (The unsatisfactory explanation: The downvote was changed into an upvote, but that happened *months* later.) So unfortunately the timeline doesn't help here.

Answer (score 5):

The reputation count is not guaranteed to be always 100% accurate. Did you removed any down-votes? Did you recalculated your reputation, because then you get previously lost points on down-voted but now deleted questions back. This points don't show up in the 'Today' section.

Have a look at the reputation audit page https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation (the last day is on the bottom) and check the number there. You can use the button there to recalculate your reputation. Then the number *should* be correct.

Comment: Well this certainly changed the numbers, and made the two the same; I also lost 10 (or 12) on the recalculation.  I didn't make any down votes. Maybe it was a deleted question.

Answer (score 4):

I think you've got those 2 points because you suggested an edit which has been accepted, and this is not listed in the detailed display.

Comment: Wouldn't such an edit be only a tag-wiki entry? (I can edit everything else with impunity, I think, no?)

Comment: @Alan: looking at your activity, I can see that you approved, not suggested, so that's probably not the cause. Perhaps somebody removed a downvote, which would add +2.

Comment: I think you mean "Perhaps somebody removed a downvote, which would **subtract -2**" `:-D`